# R - Gamma Cumulative Distribution Function

Tags: r, statistics, cdf, gamma-distribution

I want to calculate the Gamma CDF for an array of data that I have. I have calculated the alpha and beta parameters, however I am not sure of how to calculate the CDF in R,(Is there something like Matlab's gamcdf?).

I have seen some people use `fitdistr`, or `pgamma`, but I do not understand how to put the alpha and beta values or I do not need them at all?

Thanks.

Comment: `fitdistr` would be used to estimate a "best fit" of the two gamma parameters to data. `pgamma` can generate a point (or points) on the CDF function given three argumnts:  quantile within the range of the Gamma distribution, and the two parameters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A gamma distribution is defined by the two parameters, and given those two parameters, you can calculate the cdf for an array of values using pgamma.

```
# Let's make a vector
x = seq(0, 3, .01)
# Now define the parameters of your gamma distribution
shape = 1
rate = 2
# Now calculate points on the cdf
cdf = pgamma(x, shape, rate)
# Shown plotted here
plot(x,cdf)
```

[image: Gamma CDF]

Note that the Gamma has different ways it can be parameterized.  Check `?pgamma` for specifics to ensure your 2 parameters match.